# How to mock a polymorphic function with manifest in Scalamock?

Tags: scala, polymorphism, scalamock

I am trying to mock a polymorphic function belonging to a trait in scala. The method is parameterized with `[T: Manifest]`

An minimum working (or failing, should I say) example is the following:

```
class ScalaMockTest extends FlatSpec with MockFactory {

  trait testObject {
    def parameterizedFunction[T: Manifest](a: T): T
  }

  it should "not fail with scalamock" in {
    val mockObject = mock[testObject]

    (mockObject.parameterizedFunction[Int] _)
      .expects(*)
      .returns(3)

    mockObject.parameterizedFunction[Int](3)
  }
}
```

Which results in the following error: 
`org.scalamock.function.MockFunction2 cannot be cast to org.scalamock.function.MockFunction1` 
When I remove change the function definition to `def parameterizedFunction[T](a: T): T` (without the `:Manifest`), this error no longer occurs.

How can I get rid of this runtime error, and why is this happening? Unfortunately simply removing the `Manifest` is not possible because of dependencies in the code that I am actually trying to mock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little tweak in the syntax should make it work:

```
class ScalaMockTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with MockFactory {

  trait testObject {
    def parameterizedFunction[T: Manifest](a: T): T
  }

  "this" should "not fail with scalamock" in {
    val mockObject = mock[testObject]

    (mockObject.parameterizedFunction(_ : Int)(_ : Manifest[Int]))
      .expects(*, *)
      .returns(4)

    mockObject.parameterizedFunction[Int](3) shouldBe 4
  }
}
```

It's covered in [the user guide](http://scalamock.org/user-guide/advanced_topics/)

Comment: I stumbled across that link previously but wasn't able to piece this together myself, thanks! What I don't fully understand is why the `.expects` is now a function with two parameters. What should is actually being passed to the function where we match `*,*`?